# Django AppRegistryNotReady error for signals after editing apps.py to signals

Tags: django, django-signals

I'm using Django signals and getting a `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`
 The `Upload` model that I'm trying to import in `signals.py` is not loaded yet. That's why I'm getting the error. I've edited my app's `app.py` file and `settings.py` to load apps. Still I am receiving the error. My code is below:

> project/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class EngineConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'engine.signals'

    def ready(self):
        from engine import signals
```

> settings.py in installed apps

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Upload
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


@receiver(post_save, sender=Upload)
def upload_items(sender, **kwarg):
    pass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Simply used the dotted path to my model instead of trying to import it

```
@receiver(post_save, sender='app.model')
def upload_items(sender, **kwarg):
    pass
```